# Can I use flask without virtual env?

Tags: python, flask, virtual

I am having issues with flask, and now I am wondering if there's a way to use flask without virtual environment on Python. Why would we need virtual environment with flask?

```
$ sudo pip install virtualenv

$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
$ virtualenv venv
$ . venv/bin/activate
$ venv\Scripts\activate
```

I was searching on Google and couldn't find a good answer for that! If there's a way to use flask without virtual environment could you please show me how?

Comment: How about trying first? Any python package can be used outside a virtualenv

Comment: You can, of course. The only thing that virtualenv adds is the ability to completely segregate modules. That way you know concretely that your flask app doesn't use a module that your deploy server doesn't have.

Comment: Of course, I'm not sure why you'd ever *WANT* to. Virtualenv is a life saver.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can use any python library without [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable). What virtualenv does is create a sandbox environment for you so you can install whatever python libraries you want without affecting anything else on your computer. When you delete that virtual environment, all those libraries go away like it never happened.

That way you can have one project that uses version 1 or Flask and another project that uses version 2 and they won't step on each other in any way. It lets you segregate python projects so you don't have to worry about them interfering with each other.

It's generally recommended that you use it. In addition to the benefits already mentioned, it helps eliminate environmental issues between your development environment and other environments like production. Otherwise you can get into a situation where things work fine on your box but when you go to deploy it, there are problems. Usually that's because you were using the wrong version of a library without realizing it. The virtualenv system helps prevent that from happening by making sure your app only has access to the versions of the libraries you want it to. When you move your app to production the entire virtualenv sandbox goes with it so it's pretty likely it will work the same way as it did on your dev box.